# Can I modify the Action of multiple attributes at once in an AttributeManager transformer?

Tags: fme-form, fme-transformer

I'm joining a point feature class to a table in FME, to provide a spatial attribute to the tabular data.

The point feature class has about 50 attributes that I don't need -- all I want is its ID field (to join on) and its geometry. So I'm running it through an AttributeManager transformer before connecting to a FeatureMerger. However, it's tedious to select "Remove" as the Action for dozens of attributes (and I need to do this to about ten different input feature classes!)...

Is there a way to select all the attributes and change their Action to the same thing at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there are several methods I think will provide a good solution:

1. In the AttributeManager you can select lots of attributes using the Shift and Control keys, and can press the delete button (-) to remove them.
2. The AttributeKeeper transformer is a way to select a few attributes you want to keep, and delete everything else, and might work better than the AttributeManager for a case like this.
3. If the attributes to remove all have a similar naming structure, you can use the BulkAttributeRemover transformer to clean them up. It uses regular expressions to define the attributes to remove.

Comment: Oooh, yes, AttributeKeeper does seem like a better fit. Excellent assortment of options, thank you!